# Adding Google Web Font to Transactional Email?

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates

I'm attempting to add a Google Web Font (Montserrat: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat?preview.text_type=custom) in the **Marketing -> Email Templates** area and attempted to add this in two ways.

I added the `<link .. />` element in the `<header>` and also tried adding an `@import` rule in the box that allows you to add styles in the Email Template section of the admin panel.

Am I doing this wrong? The font is not showing on my sales emails. Thank you.

Comment: I would say don't expect Google Web Fonts to work too well on most email clients. At least have a fallback font and expect that to be used on most email clients. But I guess some email clients would show fonts from Google Web Fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Just to see please can you add the following to the email head template

```
<style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
</style>
```

Then in sales email edit screen add this CSS under template styles

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html#customize-email-admin

```
h1 { font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 36px; line-height: 40px;}
```

Does Google font come through? If not could be the email client.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately it's still not showing? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override header.html which is located to below path.

> app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME
> HERE}}/default/Magento_Email/email/header.html

After that add the below code in the  tag.

```
<head>
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
</head>
```

Once you added that then you can use google font like given in the below example.

> app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME
> HERE}}/default/web/css/source/_email.less

```
.wrapper-inner {
    .main-content {
        font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    p {
        font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
}
```

**Note:** Whenever you change anything into the _email.less file you have to run the commands.

Let me know if you still facing any issues.